# 3d module pose animates to another

Tags: animation, augmented-reality, aframe, webvr, 3d-model

I'm trying to do an animation of a 3D Model walking towards the user whilst in pose 'Baby--Charge' however at the end of the position animation I want the 3D models pose to change to the 'Baby--Jumpscare' pose.
I'm using A-frame for this and I'm a student so my code isn't best practice.
I've attached the model link and my code below.

Model Link
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/circus-baby-fnaf-ar-special-delivery-5b0a667c39d64a40b5f022116265081b

Code tried

Comment: its not showing my code above so just incase here it is.                                              <a-gltf-model src="#clownbaby" scale=".5 .5 .5" position="1 0.25 0" rotation="0 90 0" animation-mixer="clip: Baby--Charge" animation="property: position; dur:14000; from:1 0.25 0;to:4 0.25 0; delay:1400;" animation-mixer="from:clip: Baby--Charge;to:clip: Baby--Jumpscare"></a-gltf-model>

Comment: Might wanna share your complete code with https://glitch.com/~aframe it will be easier for people to help and suggest alternatives. best of luck.